# Better title for "Real life and death issue..."

Tags: discussion, specific-question, titles

In r.e.:

[Optimizing response times of an ambulance corp: short-term versus average](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232220/real-life-death-issue-that-requires-a-mathematical-solution)

I think it would be a good idea to give this a meaningful title.

Comment: The old title reminds me of the case recently in Italy where some geologists were sentenced to prison for failing to predict an earthquake.  "Real life and death issue..."

Comment: When I first saw "life and death", I expected to see [the Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)

Comment: @TheChaz: You [always expect the Josephus problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83837/what-is-a-real-world-application-of-polynomial-factoring/83877#comment197975_83877). :-)

Comment: Hah! Good find, @Asaf

Answer (score 3):

For now it has been changed to "Optimizing response times of an ambulance corp: short-term versus average".

Out of curiosity: now that the question title is edited, would your original question text be automatically updated to reflect it? If so that will force a never-ending cycle of improvements...

Comment: Not updated.  At least after an hour.

Comment: so, like the Fixed Point of a question title?